# Asynchronous download of an Azure blob to string with .NET 4.5 async, await

Tags: c#, azure, .net-4.5, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to implement a **fully asynchronous** blob download with .NET 4.5 async & await.

Let's assume the entire blob can fit in memory at once, and we want to hold it in a `string`.

**Code:**

```
public async Task<string> DownloadTextAsync(ICloudBlob blob)
{
    using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = blob.BeginDownloadToStream(memoryStream, null, null);
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, (r) => { blob.EndDownloadToStream(r); });
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
        {
            // is this good enough?
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            // or do we need this?
            return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container1");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob1.txt");

string text = await DownloadTextAsync(blockBlob);
```

Is this code correct and this is indeed fully asynchronous? Would you implement this differently?

**I'd appreciate some extra clarifications:**

1. `GetContainerReference` and `GetBlockBlobReference` don't need to be async since they don't contact the server yet, right?
2. Does `streamReader.ReadToEnd` need to be async or not?
3. I'm a little confused about what `BeginDownloadToStream` does.. by the time `EndDownloadToStream` is called, does my memory stream have *all* the data inside? or is the stream only open pre read?

**Update: (as of Storage 2.1.0.0 RC)**

Async now supported natively.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container1");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob1.txt");

string text = await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is this code correct and this is indeed fully asynchronous?

Yes.

> Would you implement this differently?

Yes. In particular, the `TaskFactory.FromAsync` wrappers are much more efficient if you pass in a `Begin`/`End` method pair instead of passing in an existing `IAsyncResult`. Like this:

```
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(blob.BeginDownloadToStream,
    blob.EndDownloadToStream, memoryStream, null);
```

I also prefer to wrap these up into separate extension methods so I can call it like this:

```
await blog.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
```

Note that the next version of the client libraries (2.1, currently in RC) will have `async`-ready methods, i.e., `DownloadToStreamAsync`.

> GetContainerReference and GetBlockBlobReference don't need to be async since they don't contact the server yet, right?

Correct.

> Does streamReader.ReadToEnd need to be async or not?

It does not (and should not). `Stream` is a bit of an unusual case with `async` programming. Usually, if there's an `async` method then you should use it in your `async` code, but that guideline doesn't hold for `Stream` types. The reason is that the base `Stream` class doesn't know whether its implementation is synchronous or asynchronous, so it assumes that it's synchronous and by default will fake its asynchronous operations by just doing the synchronous work on a background thread. Truly asynchronous streams (e.g., `NetworkStream`) override this and provide true asynchronous operations. Synchronous streams (e.g., `MemoryStream`) keep this default behavior.

So you *don't* want to call `ReadToEndAsync` on a `MemoryStream`.

> I'm a little confused about what BeginDownloadToStream does.. by the time EndDownloadToStream is called, does my memory stream have all the data inside?

Yes. The operation is `DownloadToStream`; that it, it downloads a blob into a stream. Since you are downloading a blob into a `MemoryStream`, the blob is entirely in memory by the time this operation completes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Correct, they don't need to be async if they're not going to be long operations, which they shouldnt' be.
2. Probably not, although I'm not familiar with this particular implementation.  I would hope that since you're waiting for the stream to end before this point there should be no network work, and thus no expensive operations, to perform at this point.  You should just be pulling data from a buffer, and it should be fast.  This is easy enough to test, however.  You can use something like Fiddler to see if there is network communication going on during that call, you can just time the method to see if it's taking long enough to appear that network IO is going on, or you could look through the docs of this specific stream implementation.  Or you could just use the async method to be safe, which I would suggest, rather than risking being mistaken.  I would be rather surprised to find that this *needed* to be async though.
3. See #2.

Comment: The docs aren't too verbose on the matter.. I guess testing is in order, I'll take a big blob and do some timing. This is so tricky and I expected it to be obvious :)

Comment: The docs are clear on the BeginDownloadToStream--the callback (in your case, the code that calls EndDownloadToStream) is called when the "operation completes".

Comment: @PeterRitchie I'm not 100% sure what the operation is exactly. Is it the entire download or just the beginning (the first query of the server). If it's the former, do I have any other way to get notified about progress or cancel if it's too long/big?

Comment: @talkol it's the entire download.  If it can't happen (too big, etc.), you'll get an exception.  I don't think CloudBlob implements progress, but you could probably do that with a `Stream` implementation like http://mel-green.com/2010/01/progressstream/

Comment: @PeterRitchie Great. So I would CloudBlob.OpenRead() to get the stream and then read it with StreamReader.ReadAsync() implementing progress myself, right?

Comment: @talkol Yes, you would just start reading (using `ReadAsync` for sure this time) without first ensuring the download ended if you wanted to stream the data.

Comment: @talkol in fact, here's an example of CloudBlob progress from Microsoft : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/03/06/asynchronous-parallel-block-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WAD-B406#fbid=lCN9J5QiTDF for some helpful best practices including why you should avoid using Memory stream as the original code does :)

One note is that you have two main options for downloading Blobs, the Cloud[Block|Page]Blob.Download[Range]To* methods and the stream provided by OpenRead(). In the case of the Download apis the entire blob (or range if requested) is issued as a single GET call and the results are streamed / written to the appropriate location, in the case of a transient fault the subrange of bytes not yet received is requested according to the retry policy.

The OpenRead methods are meant for clients who wish to process data over a longer period of time and not keep a connection open. They work by specifying a given length that will be prebuffered at the client side, when the stream runs out of pre buffered data the next sub range is requested.

Lastly, as of [2.1 RTM](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) a DownloadTextAsync method is provided that does all of this for you :) (with optional overloads to specify encoding, default is UTF8)