# Streaming an Azure blob to the client asynchronously with .NET 4.5 async, await

Tags: c#, azure, .net-4.5, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I'm implementing my own async HTTP handler with `HttpTaskAsyncHandler` and using async & await to keep it fully asynchronous.

I want to stream an azure blob directly to the client. It's true that I can redirect the client to the blob URL and have them download it directly, but let's assume I don't want to do that (my blob is private for example).

This is my current implementation:

**Code:**

```
    public async Task<bool> DownloadToStreamAsync(ICloudBlob blob, Stream stream)
    {
        bool blobFound = true; 
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = blob.BeginDownloadToStream(stream, null, null);
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, (r) =>
        {
            try
            {
                blob.EndDownloadToStream(r);
            }
            catch (StorageException)
            {
                blobFound = false;
            }
        });
        return blobFound;
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container1");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob1.txt");

        await DownloadToStreamAsync(blockBlob, context.Response.OutputStream);
    }
```

Is this code indeed fully asynchronous and will free my HTTP server to handle other clients while the streaming takes place? (ie if I had a single server thread)

Is it possible to keep the blobs compressed (GZIP) and have the client deflate them using `Content-Encoding: gzip`?

**Update: (as of Storage 2.1.0.0 RC)**

Async now supported natively.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container1");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob1.txt");

await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: WindowsAzure.Storage 2.1.0.0-rc now supports async natively - http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is asynchronous, and will free up the server request thread. See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18222057/263693) for recommendations re `TaskFactory.FromAsync`.

> Is it possible to keep the blobs compressed (GZIP) and have the client deflate them using Content-Encoding: gzip?

I have no idea. That's an interesting question; you may want to post it as a separate question.

Comment: Regarding your question about GZIP compressed blob, the answer is yes. I have tried it myself with smaller files (like JS, images etc.) and it worked fine in various browsers I tried. Not sure how it would work in a scenario where you're streaming content by reading partial data and flushing that down the stream instead of streaming the whole blob.

Comment: @GauravMantri: So you just set the header manually and then stream the pre-gzipped file, and that works fine?

Comment: The way I did was to set the `Content-Encoding` property on blob to `gzip` and when it was streamed directly from storage, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Compression is not currently supported by the client. You may of course set the header and most browsers will honor it, however if downloading via the client you would be retrieving the zipped contents rather than the uncompressed data. This is a feature request we are tracking.